# 3d cursor x,y,z does not move with mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, 3d-cursor

I have a model that has a root (main) bone added to rear of pelvis. The root bone
is for movement (animation) of model. 
 When I'm in pose mode and move model forward using the root bone, I noticed the   x,y,z 3d cursor of the mesh does not move with the mesh.

I have a feeling this will cause problems if I continue to animate. I've decided to stop researching and ask for help. I have posted 3 pictures. The first picture shows model before movement, second picture is after I move Model. The third picture is what it looks like in object mode.

Is this normal? Do I need the 3d cursor xyz  to stay with mesh when I move model in pose mode? If so how.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i've spent forty minutes doing this I apologize about the pictures. The first picture is at the end of my question. The second picture uploaded three times. The third picture did not upload at all. The third picture is not really necessary.  thanks

Comment: You can edit your post to correct the pictures. What you call "3d cursor" is the object Origin. If you want to change the position of the whole character, you should do that in Object mode, not Pose mode.

Comment: Hi, thank you. The reason I moved it in pose mode is because i'm planning to move the whole character in a animation while moving arms and legs etc. When I move the model for animation, will the object origin still stay in it's original  position? If so, is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is absolutely fine: the bones move vertices only, which have some weight related to their respective vertex group (with the same name). The object (its origin) stays still. If you move the object in object mode you will have weird issues unless you move the rig accordingly.

The usual way to animate is setting both object and rig at the center of the world in object mode, then in pose mode use the root bone to grab your character where he needs to be, and start the animation from there. The root bone can stay still while the rest of the bones are animating the mesh, or can be moved along a path in case of walk cycles or similar.